# CBPeripheralManager limitations

Tags: ios, ios6, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

What are the limitations of the new CBPeripheralManager in iOS 6? If I were crazy enough to implement the FTP (service identifier 0x1106) profile, would I be able to? Or does Apple limit which Bluetooth services an app can expose?

https://github.com/KhaosT/CBPeripheralManager-Demo seems to be a good example of the new types, but I'm not clear on how much is supported at this time, especially since CBPeripheralManager is not even available in the public docs.

Comment: I think you might be confusing Bluetooth and Bluetooth LE here. The Core Bluetooth framework only works with the LE side. All of that is completely open for you to use, but LE doesn't have a standard FTP service like normal Bluetooth does. You could create your own data transfer service for LE, however.

Comment: @BradLarson, yea just learning this stuff so definitely a bit confused. So what about HID over GATT? Sounds like that's something one could do to use an iPhone as a pointer or mouse. Does that sounds about right?

Comment: The LE side is completely application-level, not system-level, so you could add support for HID pointers, etc. over LE to your application, but they won't do anything system-wide. There is some built-in system support for standard Bluetooth HID, such as keyboards or Braille input devices, but only the ones explicitly supported by a given version of iOS and you can't do anything to add to those.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson. That clear things up. That being said, a Mac or Windows laptop might support BLE's HID over GATT profile, in which case I could hook an iPhone to a laptop as a mouse device on _that_ system, for example. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: I believe so. You should be able to simulate every aspect of an LE peripheral on an iOS device (or in the iOS Simulator on the Mac), starting with iOS 6.0. Haven't tried this myself, but I've simulated other LE devices by mocking their protocols on an iPhone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@BradLarson was a key helping out with this answer. Kudos to him for all the help in the comments. I'm answering this question just to document what was said for posterity in what I would consider an answer to my perhaps poorly worded question.

The CoreBluetooth iOS framework allows an app developer to use [Bluetooth LE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy), the low energy version of Bluetooth. BLE includes a different set of profiles so services like FTP are not available for it, although some others are. The library should be sufficient to implement these profiles. For example, it should be possible to implement [HID over GATT](http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/profiles/Pages/ProfileViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.profile.hid_over_gatt.xml).

For jailbroken devices, the [BTStack](http://code.google.com/p/btstack/) library can be used to interface with Bluetooth.

A reference I found quite useful to learning about Bluetooth is [An introduction to Bluetooth programming](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/index.html).

Comment: You should read section 3.11 of this document from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf . It contains some limitations what can be done over BLE. For example, the Bluetooth Low Energy HID Service is "implemented internally by iOS and shall not be published by third party iOS applications". When third party iOS applications discover services on the accessory, the HID Service (amongst others) is "used internally by iOS and is filtered out from the list of discovered services".